# Check wireless network status for getting accurate location in android

Tags: android

How to check network connection such as wifi or mobile networks to determine approximate    location in android.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understood what you are asking really.

1) Are you asking how to test if you are connected to a network or if is there a network available ?

`public boolean isNetworkOnline() {

```
boolean status=false;
try{
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(0);
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
        status= true;
    }else {
        netInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(1);
        if(netInfo!=null && netInfo.getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
            status= true;
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();  
    return false;
}
return status;
}
```

2) Do you want to get the location of your device ?

2.1) Why don't you get the location through gps which is more accurate ?

To get the location of your device: 
a) create a location manager object: `private   LocationManager lm;`
   `lm = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);`

b) Request location updates from what providers do you want:

```
-> GPS: lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

-> NETWORK: lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

Comment: i want to know about the status of network in location service (setting), which is used for determine approximate location from sources such as wifi and mobile.

Comment: So you want to know if the "Use wireless networks" is checked in the Location services from Settings ? If is that so, check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311834/android-dev-how-to-check-if-location-services-are-enabled

Comment: Thanks user42949,i got  solution.