# Check if Location is enabled android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-location, android-settings

Is there a way to programatically check if the Location is enabled in android?
Im talking about this setting on the phone:

[image]

Comment: @MrEngineer13 on the answer that is duplicate will the dialog sent me to this setting when i try to enable it?

Comment: Yes http://stackoverflow.com/a/10311877/1167780 will send you to settings.

Comment: You can find a more complete answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10311891/1361250