# Android show android natice pop up settings/cancel to enable location service

Tags: android, geolocation, android-location, android-geofence

I am working on an android application that uses geo location services, when the user accesses such service if location access is disabled on the device i want to call android native pop up that guides user to enabled location access. Is it possible to do this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if Location Services are enabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311834/how-to-check-if-location-services-are-enabled)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed there's even better way to achieve good location settings, without "guiding" user to turn them on, mentioned in this question:
[Enabling Location with mode High Accuracy or Battery saving without user needing to visit Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28759454/enabling-location-with-mode-high-accuracy-or-battery-saving-without-user-needing)

Since Google Play Services 7.0 you can ask system to offer user turning the settings on with one touch. It's how Google Maps are doing it.