# Enable Location Service on Onclick event in Android?

Tags: android

In my application I want to get the location of the user. If the location service is on it will get the location. Otherwise it will call `turnGPSon` but this method it not working.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnShowLocation;

    GPSTracker gps;
    Context ctx;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_location);

        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

                if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Your Location is -\nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: "
                                    + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                   // gps.showSettingsAlert();
                    turnGPSOn();

                }
            }
        });
    }
    public void turnGPSOn()
    {
        try{
            String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

            if(!provider.contains("gps"))
            { //if gps is disabled
                final Intent poke = new Intent();
                poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
                poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
                poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
                sendBroadcast(poke);
            }
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

this is my code to show dialog box for manually on Location Service

```
public void showSettingsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: If am doing off location service its not showing anything

Comment: you can check out this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175522/how-to-enable-location-access-programatically-in-android/25175756#25175756 It prompts user if their location is off

Comment: i have seen this... i dont want any dialog box for enable location service if location service is off then on without user know..

Comment: You can't do that without user's permission, previosuly their was bug which could be exploited but it has been fixed already

Comment: Means without user permission i cant enable it

Comment: yes, you can't enable it without user permission. Check this link -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/how-can-i-enable-or-disable-the-gps-programmatically-on-android

Comment: okk...thanks gautam for helping