# How to On location access programmatically in android

Tags: java, android

I am creating an app and i am **getting error** in my **location access** of mobile in app. please help me. using following code......

```
  public static boolean isLocationEnabled(Context context) {
    int locationMode = 0;
    String locationProviders;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        try {
            locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);

        } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return locationMode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF;

    }else{
        locationProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(locationProviders);
    }


}
```

i am getting error in this

> "locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);"

please tell me how to resolve it.
Thanks
[click here what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u4kD.png)

Comment: did you get permission from user? new os 6.0 you may need to acquire permission during runtime and please provide your logcat.

Comment: this my logcat  "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ContentResolver android.content.Context.getContentResolver()' on a null object reference
                                                              at com.test.MapsActivity.isLocationEnabled(MapsActivity.java:179)"

Comment: doesn't seem like a permission problem yet. it seems like it complaint about your context. Did you pass in the right context? where you call this function? in activity or fragment?

Comment: in OnCreate "isLocationEnabled(context);" Like this

Comment: this is how i called in my activity.   Utils.isLocationEnabled(this);    result successful, shown in screenshot below.

Comment: please click on  " click here what i want" in question below

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I tried your code, I am able to get location. Then you better check if your context is right. Permission required?

Comment: i want when i click on "allow button"  location access automatically ON

Comment: no, when i open my app at that my app not getting location ON.so that time i click on "allow button" location access is automatically ON

Comment: please click on  " click here what i want" in question below

Comment: Is this what you want? [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863509/how-to-programmatically-turn-off-wifi-on-android-device

Comment: i donot want wifi I want only location permission access

Comment: it is all in stackoverflow, all you need is just search [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175522/how-to-enable-location-access-programatically-in-android