# Automatically enable location when opening app

Tags: android

I want to enable location without having a dialogue box popping up when I open my App.
and i want it to enable until i turned it off manually.is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An app cannot grant itself this permission itsself, it can detect if the service is off, and prompt the user to enable it, however for security reasons, this cannot, and should not be done without input from the user.

[See here for how to prompt the user to turn on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175522/how-to-enable-location-access-programmatically-in-android)

Answer (score 6):

No, for obvious privacy reasons.

Comment: I agree with @CommonsWare. miningian Do you like if any mobile app enables any feature without your concern?

Comment: Well, do they really need your approval, or even you knowing that they inabled it anyways.... #Facebook.

Comment: Nikhil , yes I agree with you,  is there any way to turn location?  Instead dialouge pop up.