# android Kotlin - location services didn't get enabled even though location permission is granted in phone settings

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-maps, location

I am a newbie to android. I wanted to display the prompt asking permission for location and display the device's current location in the google map if user granted permission. For that, I was following this documentation -> [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/current-place-tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com) .

its full code can be seen here:

https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/4bee77d89381462be1c80b8c5986f04c471671fd/tutorials/kotlin/CurrentPlaceDetailsOnMap/app/src/main/java/com/example/currentplacedetailsonmap/MapsActivityCurrentPlace.kt

Also referred these sites:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-show-current-location-on-a-google-map-on-android-using-kotlin

https://www.javatpoint.com/kotlin-android-google-map-current-location

Everywhere it seems they have done as I tried .

**Issue Facing :**

The app is showing the prompt asking for location permission but even though user granted location permission, the `Location Service` didn't get started automatically. I have tested it in multiple phones which are of different android versions but the result is same.

Please see the screenshots of it from my phone :

1. [Location Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMJFf.jpg)
2. [Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hB3Vz.jpg)
3. [App Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78RA7.jpg)

Why the app is not starting the `Location Service` by itself even though it has provided with Location permissions?

How can I fix this? Any help is much appreciated.

Everything I did to implement this is created a project with `Empty Activity` .

Added the google play services' maps & location dependencies to the `build.gradle` file.

Then changed the below listed files with the code given below.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.mapplot

import android.Manifest
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
import com.example.mapplot.ui.theme.MapPlotTheme
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng

class MainActivity : FragmentActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    private lateinit var map: GoogleMap
    private lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private var locationPermissionGranted = false
    private var lastKnownLocation: Location? = null
    private val defaultLocation = LatLng(-33.8523341, 151.2106085)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    }

    override fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap) {
        this.map = map

        updateLocationUI()
        getDeviceLocation()
    }

    private fun getLocationPermission() {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this.applicationContext,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            )
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            locationPermissionGranted = true
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            )
        }
    }


    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        locationPermissionGranted = false
        when (requestCode) {
            PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION -> {

                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    locationPermissionGranted = true
                }
            }

            else -> super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        }
        updateLocationUI()

    }

    private fun updateLocationUI() {
        if (map == null) {
            return
        }
        try {
            if (locationPermissionGranted) {
                map?.isMyLocationEnabled = true
                map?.uiSettings?.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = true
            } else {
                map?.isMyLocationEnabled = false
                map?.uiSettings?.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = false
                lastKnownLocation = null
                getLocationPermission()
            }
        } catch (e: SecurityException) {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.message, e)
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun getDeviceLocation() {
        
        try {
            if (locationPermissionGranted) {
                val locationResult = fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation
                locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        
                        lastKnownLocation = task.result
                        if (lastKnownLocation != null) {
                            map?.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                LatLng(lastKnownLocation!!.latitude,
                                    lastKnownLocation!!.longitude), DEFAULT_ZOOM.toFloat()))
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Current location is null. Using defaults.")
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: %s", task.exception)
                        map?.moveCamera(
                            CameraUpdateFactory
                                .newLatLngZoom(defaultLocation, DEFAULT_ZOOM.toFloat()))
                        map?.uiSettings?.isMyLocationButtonEnabled = false
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (e: SecurityException) {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.message, e)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private val TAG = MainActivity::class.java.simpleName
        private const val DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15
        private const val PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1

        private const val KEY_CAMERA_POSITION = "camera_position"
        private const val KEY_LOCATION = "location"
       
        private const val M_MAX_ENTRIES = 5
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mapplot.MainActivity"
    >

</fragment>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.mapplot">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MapPlot"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MapPlot">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Map Plot</string>
    <string name="google_maps_key">MY_API_KEY_HERE</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

The permissions request just grants your app permission to access location when location is available. To actually request that the location services be re-enabled (if they're turned off) you can use [`SettingsClient`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient) and `LocationSettingsRequest` from Google Play Services.

```kotlin
LocationServices.getClient(context)
  .checkLocationSettings(
    LocationSettingsRequest.builder()
      .addLocationRequest(
        LocationRequest.Builder(/* intervalMillis= */ 5000)
          .setPriority(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
          .build()
      )
  )
  .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    try {
      task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
      // If you reach this line, settings are already enabled
    } catch (ex: ApiException)
      when (ex.statusCode) {
        LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED ->
          // Launch the settings UI
          (ex as ResolvableApiException)
            .startResolutionForResult(
              activity,
              REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION_SETTINGS,
            )
        else ->       
          // Couldn't change settings
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you please say, exactly in which function of the `MainActivity` file, shall I include the code you provided? If this code is not to be added inside an exiting function but to be  included as a separate function, From which function of  my `MainActivity` file ,shall I initiate the call to this new function?

Comment: +1. What if `GooglePlayServices` is not available in the app-installed device? How can one enable it if we are using `LocationManager`? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25175756/6576302)

Comment: @kevin-coppock Why do this when(ex.statusCode) to after the condition check do the cast and not just if(ex is ResolvableApiException) which will already do the cast and check the condition? There are any possibility that ex.statusCode is RESOLUTION_REQUIRED and yet the exception is not ResolvableApiException?