# Access only location manager

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

I want to check location service is open or not when the app starts. 
I use this code :

LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if(!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))

However this code check GPS open or not. In my program, i don't need GPS. I just need location access permission. How can i do that?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please check This Like Helpfule for u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311834/how-to-check-if-location-services-are-enabled

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring on using either Wifi/Data on accessing location:

LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER

Comment: Glad to help you then! Please do not forget to accept my answer as correct.