# How to find the GPS and Network provider status without consuming GPS?

Tags: android, networking, gps, location, locationlistener

How to listen for GPS and Network Provider status without consuming the GPS. 
I want to know the status alone. I dont want to get the location information.

I have used the below code,

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

When using the above code, the GPS icon is always splashing in the notification bar. It means that it is always consuming the GPS. I don't want the GPS to be consumed just to check the GPS status. Because this is draining the battery power. 
Checking the GPS ON or OFF is different from consuming the GPS.

And also I have explored and found the way to check the GPS status alone 
["GpsStatus.Listener".](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.Listener.html)

But I want to know both the GPS and Network provider status. I don't want the location information.

Please help me on this.

Comment: So you know how to check GPS status now?  Have you searched for how to check if there's an internet connection?  Because there are tips for that all over the place.

Comment: Yes I was able to get the GPS status. But to check the GPS status why it's consuming the GPS always. Check the status is different from consuming the GPS. I want to check not consume. When I was using requestLocationUpdates or "GpsStatus.Listener". Both is consuming the GPS to return the GPS status.

Comment: Well 5 seconds with Google turned this up, maybe it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311834/how-to-check-if-location-services-are-enabled

Comment: Yes that i know already. Always I want to listen for the location provider status. Not at the time of location request.

Comment: I see, I'm not sure if the system broadcasts events when the provider status changes.  You may have to poll.

Comment: I have polled for GPS status, It is always consuming the GPS when using the above code.

Comment: Checking if the provider is enabled (like in the answer I linked to) consumes GPS?  If so, what exactly do you mean by consuming GPS?

Comment: First understand my requirement. I dont want to check for gps status for a particular time. I want to get a callback when the GPS status changed to or from enable to disable. I have referred all the sites in the web. There is no way to do that. So Currently am checking the GPS and network status as per the link you have shared.

Comment: Right, I've got it.  But you're saying there's still a problem right?  Or is everything solved now?

Comment: Am not finding any solution that exactly meets my requirement. So Currently I am checking the GPS and network status as per the link you have shared. Share the answer if you know. Thanks for your help Mr nasch.

Comment: So the problem is it "consumes GPS" when you check the status?  What does that mean?

Comment: Yes By using the above given code if I check the GPS status it always consumes the GPS which means u can find the GPS icon in notification bar.

Answer (score 0):

Find my answer below,

Registered local broadcast receiver to update the UI whenever the location provider status changes,

> **getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(mGpsNetworkStatusChangeReceiver,
>   new IntentFilter(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION));**

Below is my **Broadcast receiver**:

```
public class GpsNetworkStatusReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = GpsNetworkStatusReceiver.class
            .getSimpleName();

    private AppUtil mAppUtilInstance = AppUtil.getInstance();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mAppUtilInstance.logDebugMessage(TAG,
                "GpsNetworkStatusReceiver - onReceive");

    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //check the GPS and NEtwork Provider Status and update the UI
    boolean gpsEnabled = mLocationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean networkEnabled = mLocationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

}

}
```