# How to check if location is on and in high priority on API 18 and below

Tags: android

Tried this:

```
String locationProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(getActivity().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
Log.d(TAG_MAP, locationProviders);
```

Output is: gps,network

Are phones that are API 18 and below dont' have HIGH_ACCURACY Priority?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I assume you're wondering how using `Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED`, which is depricated in API level 19, is different from using `Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE`, which was introduced in API level 19.

With `Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE`, you have these values (you probably already know this):

> LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY, LOCATION_MODE_SENSORS_ONLY,
>   LOCATION_MODE_BATTERY_SAVING, or LOCATION_MODE_OFF

You can map these values to `Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED` in this way:

> LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY : "gps,network"
>
> LOCATION_MODE_SENSORS_ONLY : "gps"
>
> LOCATION_MODE_BATTERY_SAVING : "network"
>
> LOCATION_MODE_OFF : ""

Note that in code, it's best to reference constants `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER` and `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` instead of just "gps" and "network".

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311834/how-to-check-if-location-services-are-enabled/22980843#22980843) as a reference, you could do something like this:

```
public static int getLocationMode(Context context) {
    int locationMode = 0;
    String locationProviders;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        try {
            locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);

        } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    } else {
        locationProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(locationProviders)) {
          locationMode = Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF;
        }
        else if (locationProviders.contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) && locationProviders.contains(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
          locationMode = Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY;
        }
        else if (locationProviders.contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
           locationMode = Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_SENSORS_ONLY;
        }
        else if (locationProviders.contains(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
           locationMode = Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_BATTERY_SAVING;
        }

    }

    return locationMode;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this function. I tested on API 21 and API 16

```
public static boolean checkHighAccuracyLocationMode(Context context) {
    int locationMode = 0;
    String locationProviders;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
        //Equal or higher than API 19/KitKat
        try {
            locationMode = Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
            if (locationMode == Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY){
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        //Lower than API 19
        locationProviders = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

        if (locationProviders.contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) && locationProviders.contains(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Remember that HIGH_ACCURACY mode means both GPS and Network Provider is enabled by the user. Otherwise this function will return false.

Answer (score 0):

Try this **Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE**

```
String gpsStatus = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
```

You can use this checking

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 &&
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    Log.e("gpsStatus", "LOCATION PERMISSION NOT GRANTED");
} else {

    Log.d("gpsStatus", "LOCATION PERMISSION GRANTED");

    if (gpsStatus.indexOf("gps", 0) < 3) {
        Log.d("gpsCheck", "DEVICE LOCATION PERMISSION IS GRANTED");
     
    } else {
        Log.e("gpsCheck", "DEVICE LOCATION PERMISSION NOT GRANTED");
    }
}
```