# Requesting Permission at run time Android Marshmallow not working

Tags: android, android-permissions

i disabled the location of mobile but it still show Location already granted in the toast.

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=23){

        showRunTimePermission();
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_v2, container,
            false);




    return view;
}
```

//shows alert dialog if location is disabled.

```
private void showRunTimePermission() {
   if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
           ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
       requestLocationPermission();
   }else{
       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Location already granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

}

private void requestLocationPermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){
        final AlertDialog locationDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setCancelable(false).create();
        View dialogView = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.dialog_location_access, null);
        TextView okBtn= (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_location_ok_button);
        okBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ActivityCompat
                        .requestPermissions(getActivity(), PERMISSIONS_LOCATION,
                                LOCATION_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
            }
        });
        TextView denyBtn= (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_location_deny_button);
        denyBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                locationDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        locationDialog.setView(dialogView);

        locationDialog.show();

    }else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), PERMISSIONS_LOCATION,
                LOCATION_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

// if the location is on or off the toast will appear accordingly.

```
    @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[]        permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode==LOCATION_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST){
        if (grantResults.length == 1 &&
                grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Location granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Location permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }else {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enabled location and granted permission for location are two different things. To check if location is enabled: [How to check if Location Services are enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311834/how-to-check-if-location-services-are-enabled)

Answer (score 0):

Well, In this before asking permission you need to check that whether permission is granted or not and then you have to ask permission!

Try this [Library](https://github.com/UttamPanchasara/RuntimePermission) this will help you to ask permission Automatically you just need to pass permission Name.