# getCurrentLocation() of FusedLocationProviderClient returns a success but without the location?

Tags: android, kotlin, fusedlocationproviderclient

While it's expected that LastLocation doesn't provide a location for the first time if it's unknown. I didn't expect to see the same issue with `GetCurrentLocation`.

```
val mFusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(mContext)
 mFusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, object: CancellationToken() {
                override fun onCanceledRequested(p0: OnTokenCanceledListener) = CancellationTokenSource().token
                override fun isCancellationRequested() = false
            }).addOnCompleteListener { it ->
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    val location: Location = it.result
                    // Why can this be null if it was a success?
                }
            }
```

How can `it.isSuccessful` be true and at the same time, showing the `it.result` (location) as null?

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's a behaviour of [Task](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/tasks/Task.html). When you call `addOnCompleteListener`, it returns a result, while `addOnFailureListener` listens to Task fail. In this case [getCurrentLocation()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient#public-abstract-tasklocation-getcurrentlocation-int-priority,-cancellationtoken-cancellationtoken) tries to access/compute a current location:

> This may return a cached location if a recent enough location fix
> exists, or may compute a fresh location. If unable to retrieve a
> current location fix, null will be returned.

`addOnFailureListener` will return an error. Maybe permissions were not granted or GPS provider didn't work, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks. Permissions were 100% granted though. My research shows that it could be indeed that GPS lock couldn't be acquired.  But this doesn't really solve the problem. How can I retry this if it has failed the first time around though?

Comment: @Houman, sorry, I ambiguously wrote. I meant `addOnFailureListener` might return an exception in some cases (maybe permissions, hardware or Play Services error). Probably you should ask   
getLastLocation()  or requestLocationUpdates().

Comment: I made something for `requestLocationUpdates` here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52587361/fusedlocationclient-not-calling-onlocationresult.

Comment: Thank you. I checked your sample. But you are using `lastLocation` in your example instead of `getCurrentLocation` though. Unless I should be combining them, although it's not quite the same thing. LastLocation could be older than current location, that couldn't be fetched.

Comment: @Houman, thank you for a feed back. Agree with you, but currently I cannot offer more.