# Location permission dialog box not appearing on clicking location FAB

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a map fragment. In the map fragment, I am using a FAB button for getting user's current location and showing it on the map. I have declared the following permissions in the Manifest file.
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>`

Now there are 2 cases:

(1) **The user's location was already turned on**: In this case when I press location FAB button, it animates the map to users current location and shows the blue dot on map representing user's current location. This is working as expected

(2) **The user's location was off**: Now this is where I have problem. I want the dialog box to appear, when the user clicks on the location FAB , requesting user to turn on his location & if location granted then move to users current location. But, when I press the FAB, nothing is happening. The following is the code for on setOnClickListener for the location FAB.

```
locationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("MapFragment", "Location button pressed" );
            try {
                Log.v("MapFragment", "Inside try" );

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.v("MapFragment", "inside if 0.7" );
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                    Log.v("MapFragment", "inside if 1" );
                    return;
                }
                currentLocation = getLastKnownLocation();
                if (currentLocation != null) {
                    Log.v("MapFragment", "inside if 2" );
                    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()), 17);
                    googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                    locationButton.getDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorPrimary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                }


            } catch (Exception e){
                checkLocationPermission();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please turn on Location from the Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });
```

the `getLastKnownLocation()` function is as follows:

```
private Location getLastKnownLocation() {
    //Create a location manager object instance
    LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //Get all the different providers which can give current location info
    List<String> providers = mLocationManager.getProviders(true);
    //Initialising the location to be null
    Location bestLocation = null;
    //Creating a for loop to go through all the location providers and get the location
    for (String provider : providers) {

        //if permission is not granted, then get the permission

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
        //Get the last known location from the data provider
        Location l = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        //If the last know location provided by the data provider is null then ignore the provider and move to the next one.
        if (l == null) {
            continue;
        }

        if (bestLocation == null || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
            bestLocation = l;
        }
    }
    return bestLocation;
}
```

The log messages that I get on pressing FAB in case 2 are as follows

```
01-16 13:52:15.728 18227-18227/in.map.app V/MapFragment: Location button pressed
01-16 13:52:15.728 18227-18227/in.map.app V/MapFragment: Inside try
```

Comment: You just need to check if location is turned on. Checking for permission isn't sufficient. Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311834/how-to-check-if-location-services-are-enabled

Comment: The above comment is more helpful then answer given by Kushaal Singla.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override this method and accordingly to do next operation.

```
void onRequestPermissionsResult (int requestCode, 
                String[] permissions, 
                int[] grantResults)
```